# Passing a google_credential.json file as an environment variable in AWS EMR Cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gcloud, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I am fairly new to AWS EMR. So i am trying to get data from google cloud bigquery into aws via emr. I have managed to do this in lambda but since size is huge need to switch to emr.
Using Library

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

Now need to pass GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.json file as environment variable in emr. So how should i go about it. A step by step direction are much appreciated.
Second question is can i do this with glue too. I already tried with connectors available online but the data i got was very messed up. So i wish to try with this library only but no idea how to proceed in glue with this.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You probably want to use [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) rather than referencing Service Account keys. If you **must** use a Service Account key, have a look at [Loading credentials from environment variables](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#user-content-loading-credentials-from-environment-variables)

Comment: @DazWilkin I have tried doing it with export method. It seems to work in Pycharm but fails in emr and throws and error that google_credentials.json not found.